# Calculate my dynamic and my static input together

Tags: php, dynamic, input, static, sum

I have a function static who can calculate all my static input:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#input5,#tempsam ').each(function () {
        $(this).on('change',recalculate);
    });
});
function recalculate () {
    if(isNaN(this.value))
        alert("Please enter a number");
    else {
        var b = 0;
        if (($('#input5').val() !== b) && ($('#input2').val() !== b) && ($('#tempsam').val() !== b )) {
            var a = 40;
            var value1 = $('#input1').val() == "" ? 0 :  parseFloat($('#input1').val());
            var value7 = $('#tempsam').val() == "" ? 0 :  parseFloat($('#tempsam').val());
            var total =  value5 + value2  + value7
            $('#result').val(total);
        }
    }
}
```

How I calculate my dynamic input and my static one?

Here is how I calculate my static one each day:

```
//jeudi calcul
function checkfieldjeudi()
{
    var dynamicjeudi = document.getElementsByClassName("dynamicjeudi");
    var itemCount5 = dynamicjeudi.length;
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < itemCount5; i++) {
            total = total + parseFloat(dynamicjeudi[i].value);
            total = total + parseFloat(document.getElementById('input5').value);
    }
    document.getElementById('totaljeudi').value = total;
}
checkfieldjeudi();
```

How I make dynamic jeudi

```
$('#calculTempsdivjeu').append(
                (    '<input id="calculTempsdivjeu' + counterjeudi + '" name="calculTempsdivjeu[]' + '" type="number"  onchange="checkfieldjeudi();"  size="10" min="0" max="24" value="0" class="dynamicjeudi" onblur="autre();" onfocus="enter();"/>')    
                )   //désactive champs précédent.
```

Here my static jeudi

```
<div id="calculTempsdivjeu">
                        <input step="any" type="number" id="totaljeudi"  class="totaljeudi"  onchange="checkfieldjeudi();"  name="totaljeudi" size="10" min="0" max="24" value="0"  onblur="autre();" onfocus="enter();"/>

                        <input step="any"  type="number" onblur="autre();" onfocus="enter();"  onchange="checkfieldjeudi();"  id="input5" class="temps" name="tempsje"  max="24" min="0" value="0" />
                    </div>
```

Comment: its hard cause its a lot of code its about 1500 line. I show the essential like a dynamic input how its calculate and one of static one how its calculate

Comment: its take class from my input ( jeudi in french and thursday in english) so its take all my dynamic input with class dynamic jeudi, its count it and make a total for jeudi . My goal after its calculate al total of each day

Comment: Your question is not clear that's why i am too confusing about this...

Comment: here we go I edited I show my thurdays